# Neo4j v4.1.5 Community Edition CREATE INDEX doesn't recognise OPTIONS

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create an index on Neo4j 4.1.5 Community Edition using CYPHER with OPTIONS however it doesn't work.

Command:

```
CREATE INDEX index_content_name IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:__Content) ON (n.name) OPTIONS { indexProvider: 'lucene+native-3.0' }
```

Error:

```
Invalid input 'O': expected whitespace, comment, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 77 (offset: 76))
"CREATE INDEX index_content_name IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:__Content) ON (n.name) OPTIONS { indexProvider: 'lucene+native-3.0'
```

Is this functionality disabled on the Community edition?

If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: Apologies - it's 4.1.5. Question updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OPTIONS` clause was added in Neo4j 4.2.0 ( See changelog here : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-4.2-changelog#cypher-2 )

When reading the documentation, make sure you select the correct version of your Neo4j server :

[image]